# Saving custom $variables to access in different PS sessions

Tags: powershell, variables

So forewarning, I'm still pretty new to powershell so apologies if I've missed something obvious.

I have a couple of script commands I run on a regular basis to do AD-related stuff on our RDS servers. There are 3 servers, and the user could be dumped on to any one of them when signing in. A lot of commands for stuff I want to do don't work If you specify the wrong computer, and checking which one the user is on is a pain.

What I WANT to do is make an $RDS_Servers variable that persists between PS sessions and reboots so I don't have to type it out each time and go through the legwork. I want it to be a $variable specifically for versatility. I've figured out how to save it as a script so it can be called via RDS_Servers.ps1, but that's clunky and hard to insert into a script written on the fly as opposed to a nice $variable.

What I have done so far is run the following:

$RDS_Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=2016 RDS,OU=Remote Desktop,OU=Servers,OU=Computers,OU=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX"

This returns a list of all the objects in the RDS server OU, which is what I want. A variable that contains objects that can be called on demand. This is assigned to $RDS_Servers, and can be dumped into a script to for example search a users AD object via something like Get-ADuser -computer $RDS_Server -user UserX, so that it can find them without having to look up what server they're on.

The problem here is that while this works fine and dandy on a per-session basis, the thing I want to do is somehow save $RDS_Servers as a "default" variable that persists between sessions, so that If I want to do some work in PS on an AD user, I can just insert $RDS_Servers each time instead of having to specify the variable each session.

tl;dr dont know how to save variables between sessions, pls halp :o

/verbose

Answer (score 0):

Variables have a scope and they are only available in the scope defined. This is documented in the built-in help files here:

[About_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes%20...)

```
Get-Help -Name about_Scopes
```

Once you close a session, all resources are gone.

You can place any code or values you like to use in a static file that you can use your script to read back in as needed. Store that file on a central file share so that you can get to it from any machine that you allow access to read it.

Or you can create and use PowerShell profile to hold any environment configuration you choose.

[About_Profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles)

```
Get-Help -Name about_Profiles
```

The profile is just another .ps1 the sits in the current users profile folder. Anything in the profile is loaded every time PowerShell starts. Regardless of what you will do after PowerShell loads up.